# Is there a reason why make_reverse_iterator(make_reverse_iterator(it)) results in a different type?

Tags: c++, std

I would think that:

```cpp
static_assert(is_same_v<
    decltype(make_reverse_iterator(make_reverse_iterator(it)))
  , decltype(it)>);
```

would compile, but it doesn't.  Is there some reason why this is?  I can see this as potentially resulting in larger generated code when writing templates.

This isn't that difficult to implement:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T make_reverse_iterator(reverse_iterator<T> it) {
  return it.base();
}
```

and would result in a smaller binary if double or more reversals are done when calling a template function, especially if that function were to say call itself recursively using a reverse_iterator of what it was called with without complicating the code with other specializations.

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: It might be possible IMO, but would require more work.

Comment: A revere iterator of a reverse iterator should generally have the same behavior as the original iterator, but there is no requirement for `make_reverse_iterator` to implement the logic necessary to identify that a reverse iterator is being "unreversed". And for that to work, the original iterator type needs to be deduced from the reversed iterator which I'm not sure is available.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yes, that is what I mean.  Why isn't it a requirement.  It's not that difficult to implement, it would be clearer and would result in a smaller binary.

Comment: @Adrian feel free to [submit a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal)

Comment: @Adrian Generally the reason a feature doesn't exist is either because nobody has asked for this feature so no proposal exists, or the proposal was rejected. I suspect nobody has asked for this because it doesn't seem that necessary. You can try to write a proposal, if you willing to put in the work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I guess I just thought that sort of thing would be pretty obvious.

Comment: hmm.. reverse of reverse cannot be incremented if pointing to last element of original range... because it was ' begin' of  intermediate?

Comment: @Adrian The standardization committee is often hesitant to implement convenience features as it has painted itself into corners before. Once you add exceptions and special cases you can't easily  take those back without breaking compatibility. What you might see more often now is basic functionality, and once the feature becomes more mature bells and whistles can be added once the community has build experience and confidence in how the feature is used and how it might evolve. C++ has never been a language that favors brevity, convenience or gadgets, relative to other languages at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple question whose answer explains this:

Is the return value of `make_reverse_iterator` a `reverse_iterator`?

See, a reverse iterator is not just an iterator that runs backwards. It's a type. Or rather, it's a template which generates a family of types. And that template is expected to provide certain behavior; that behavior is what makes it a reverse iterator.

And this is behavior that is not required to be provided by a non-`reverse_iterator` type. A `reverse_iterator<reverse_iterator<I>>` is not the same thing as `I`. You can't get the `base` of `I`, for example.

If a user calls `make_reverse_iterator`, it is their right to expect that they will get a `reverse_iterator`, with all the powers and privileges provided by that template. To return anything else would be tantamount to lying to the user.

What you seem to want is `make_iterator_go_backwards`: a function that returns some iterator type that goes backwards through the sequence. And that's a valid thing to want.

But that thing is not spelled `make_reverse_iterator`. If you have a function called, `make_some_type`, it should return `some_type`.

Comment: Yes it is a type that has associated behaviour attached to it.  When you call `make_reverse_iterator`, a dev could expect it to generate a `reverse_iterator` template type, but more usefully, they could expect it to generate a self-inverse type.  Both types are iterators that has reverse iterator semantics from the original when adding, subtracting and indexing upon it, but a self-inverse type can make the code more symmetrical resulting in easier to read and prove code.  This isn't lying, this is simply making the dev's life easier, and those who read the code afterwards.

Comment: A `make_iterator_go_backwards` function could be used, but IMHO, lacks grace.

Comment: @Adrian: "*This isn't lying*" The function name clearly indicates that it makes `reverse_iterator`s. If it doesn't make a `reverse_iterator`, then the function name is a lie. It's like saying that `make_tuple` shouldn't return a `tuple` if you only give it a single value, because that would "make the dev's life easier" in some way.

Comment: By the same logic, `make_iterator_go_backwards` would make an `iterator_go_backwards` type. Better not to use the prefix `make_` at all then.

Comment: @Adrian: But there is no "iterator_go_backwards" type. There *is* a `tuple` type, a `reverse_iterator` type, `shared_ptr` type, etc. Functions that are `make_*` where `*` is a typename are expected to make that type because... that's their name.